# Interpolation of 3D data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have data in 3D. I would like to interpolate this data layer by layer (in the plane X, Y) because calculating each layer takes a lot of time.

I try to use the interp2D function and loop through the layers but f seems to apply only to the last value of i0.

```
X = np.linspace(10., 15., 21)
Y = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 10)
for i0 in np.arange(N):
    f = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, data[:,:,i0], kind='linear')

Xnew = np.linspace(10., 15., 41)
Ynew = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 20)
datanew = f(Xnew,Ynew)
```

How can I interpolate each layer of my data?

Thanks

Comment: what is you value for N?

Comment: The value for N is 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are creating the interpolation function for each layer and then throwing it away before creating it for the next one. That's why only the last one is still definined when you interpolate onto your new grid.

If `i0` is indexing each "layer" of your data and you're interpolating within each layer only, surely you need to create your interpolation function, `f`, for each layer and update accordingly each time round the loop. Something like the following (note you may need to `rollaxis` on `datanew` to get them back in the order you want):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

N = 64
data = np.random.random((21, 10, N))
X = np.linspace(10., 15., 21)
Y = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 10)
Xnew = np.linspace(10., 15., 41)
Ynew = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 20)
datanew = np.empty((N, 41, 20))
for i0 in np.arange(N):
    f = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, data[:,:,i0].T, kind='linear')
    datanew[i0] = f(Ynew,Xnew)
datanew = np.rollaxis(datanew, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks.
The only problem with this is that I need to do the interpolation everytime I want to change Xnew and Ynew. For my current case this is not a big deal because my data is relatively small.

Comment: You could store a list of interpolation objects and index them f[i0](Ynew,Xnew).

Answer (score 5):

> I try to use the interp2D function and loop through the layers but f seems to apply only to the last value of i0.

You are overwriting the value of your interpolant, `f`, on each iteration of your `for` loop, so by the time you have finished looping over `i0` values `f` will correspond only to the last Z-plane of `data`. Using your current approach, you would need to call `f` inside the `for` loop, e.g.:

```
# some example data for test purposes
N = 64
data = np.random.randn(10, 21, N)

X = np.linspace(10., 15., 21)
Y = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 10)
Xnew = np.linspace(10., 15., 41)
Ynew = np.linspace(0.05, 1.85, 20)

# initialize output array
datanew = np.empty((Ynew.shape[0], Xnew.shape[0], N), data.dtype)

for i0 in np.arange(N):
    f = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, data[:,:,i0], kind='linear')

    # fill in this Z-slice
    datanew[:,:,i0] = f(Xnew,Ynew)
```

---

You could eliminate the `for` loop by interpolating over all of your Z-planes simultaneously. One way to do this would be using [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator):

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

Z = np.arange(N)

itp = RegularGridInterpolator((Y, X, Z), data, method='linear')

grid = np.ix_(Ynew, Xnew, Z)
datanew2 = itp(grid)
```

Here I also use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to construct an 'open mesh' from the coordinates that you want to interpolate `data` at.